# Tab Widget Issue when use android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in Grid View but working for other Tab

Tags: android, permissions, tabs, android-manifest, android-orientation

I am stuck with my issue.Thing is that its a custom Tab Widget.In that have multiple 
tab like  `Home` - `News` - `Abc` - `PQR` .

The Activity should be for `both orientation like portrait and landscape`. so for that each tab have `two xml` for portrait which is store at `layout-port/file.xml` and landscape which store at `layout-land/file.xml`

For manage orientation portrait to landscape i have added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` rule tag in each activity.

- `TAB_SAMPLE.java` Tab file.
- `TAB_GROUP_ACTIVITY` each Tab Group activity File
- `file.java` Task file

**After all this stuff i get issue here :**

If i `add`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`rule tag in tab_sample` activity then its working perfect. like manage different view. port to land and land to port but its not working in Home.java.

Now if i `remove android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" rule tag in tab_sample` activity then its working for Home activity not for News.java

Mean when i change the orientation its keeping same xml form port not use from layout-land.in the sense its call OnCreate() again.

So as i found `may be issue is in Tab Widget.`

**Update**

Now after tracing my code i get that main issue is in grid view activity because its only activity which is not working.

`Issue is between Tab host v/s Grid View`. I don't know why its not taking layout-land xml file. i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339255/change-layout-while-orientation-change-at-runtime-in-a-fragment-without-recreati) as same issue but no replay on that question also

see in Detail [manifestfile.xml](http://pastie.org/5896221)
I want to maintain both portrait and landscape in all activity.

[Both XML File](http://pastie.org/5925648)

Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oooohhh Finally i got the solution for above issue. It's was very difficult.

For maintain the state of orientation Landscape to portrait and vice-versa we generally adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` property tag under activity.

But here `may be issue is Tab_Group_ Activity` due to that i am not able to maintain state in GridView. `Grid_File.java` is **Only single java file which was not handling the orientation rest of  all other working perfectly.**

Now if i `remove android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` from `TAB_SAMPLE.java` then **Its handling only `Grid_File.java` not others.**

```
mean that was keeping same Layout XML in landscape also where i have two separate XML File.
```

**Here is my solution:**

I have `add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in `TAB_SAMPLE.java` *as well as* 
`implement onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` and set Number of column of grid. like `gridView.setNumColumns(6);`

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // gridView.setSelection(index);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {

            // Log.e("On Config Change", "LANDSCAPE");
            gridView.setNumColumns(6);

        } else
        {

            // Log.e("On Config Change", "PORTRAIT");
            gridView.setNumColumns(4);
        }
    }
```

Generally we are  adding either `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` tag under activity or `implementing onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` but here i have written both.

Comment: @Mitesh do you know about my query ?