# How to slide to imageView in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I have a layout in which i have two button:

1)back
2)help

and `ScollView` in which i place two image Views:

1) firstImageVeiw
1) SecondImageVeiw

first image View will be displayed on front and second is placed beneath the  1st image.
Now i want that if i click on help button the the scrollView automatically slides to 2nd image view.

Any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scrollview's [`scrollTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) method

```
helpbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     yourscrollview.scrollTo(0, yourImageView.getTop());
   }
  });
```

At runtime you can get the location of every view object with

- [getleft()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft%28%29)
- [getTop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop%28%29)
- [getRight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRight%28%29)
- [getBottom()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBottom%28%29)

Comment: ok how can i get the whole area of ScrollView so that i can assume my secondImage is palced on which coordinates??

Comment: @RKN can you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561693/tab-widget-issue-when-use-androidconfigchanges-orientationkeyboardhidden-in  i have some issue about oriention but scroll can help only me some time

Comment: @RKN thankyou. its working but ites not giving sliding effect. yourscrollview.scrollTo(0, yourImageView.getTop()) directly moves to the imageview . is there any possibility to give sliding effect??