# Handling Screen orientation in android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

This app requires both portrait and landscape orientations. Here I am creating "layout-land" folder in resource folder for landscape orientation.While I am doing orientation activity is taking the XML from "layout-land" but activity is restarting.

So to avoid restarting,in manifest I am using the following permissions:

```
<android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

While I am using the above permissions activity is not restarting but it is unable to take the XML from "layout-land" folder.

Here I need:
1. Avoid restarting an activity
                   
2. Making an activity to take the XML from "layout-land" folder.
     I am new to android.Please help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "restarting" of activity?

Comment: use this won't restart your activity when rotating the phone. android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 2):

That's the way Android works.  You need to choose one of three options:

1. Use the exact same layout for portait and landscape; then, you can use `configChanges` as above. This can work even if you do have a few minor changes, if you can keep the majority of the layout the same and just make a few items visible/invisible based on orientation.
2. Use different layouts; then, you can keep `configChanges`, but you have to implement loading of the new layout yourself in `onConfigurationChanged`, including taking all the values from the old views and adding them to the new (anything that was set at run time: text values, user entered edit texts, check box states, etc).
3. Remove the `configChange` line from the manifest, and implement `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. These two will give you a chance to save any values you want and restore them around the restart of your activity. Basically the same as two, but you don't have to manually reset the view.

I highly suggest 1 if at all possible. If you must use a landscape specific layout, going route 3 is the easiest. I'm normally a big fan of setting configChanges, but it doesn't work well if you need a completely different landscape layout.

Comment: Please can you see once [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561693/tab-widget-issue-when-use-androidconfigchanges-orientationkeyboardhidden-in) i am getting same issue

Comment: Hi Gabe Thanks for your suggestions.I will try those things.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following.

```
   <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" />
```

My activity is not restarted when switching orientation on my Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in your android menifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

if you want unspecified

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```