# Android fragments added in wrong order after screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having a problem with fragment ordering when the screen orientation changes during a custom animation of my fragment transition.

If I rotate the screen at exactly the right time, the fragments are added with the `MyFragment2` in the position where `MyFragment1` should be.

I am adding my fragments as follows:

```
final FragmentManager fm = activity.get().getFragmentManager();
final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

ft.setCustomAnimations(
        R.animator.slide_in_left,
        R.animator.slide_out_top,
        R.animator.slide_in_bottom,
        R.animator.slide_out_right);

ft.replace(R.id.container,
        MyFragment1.newInstance(), MyFragment1.TAG);

ft.add(R.id.container,
        MyFragment2.newInstance(),MyFragment12.TAG)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

I have been searching for many hours for information about this problem. I have seen information here [Android multiple fragment transaction ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504790/android-multiple-fragment-transaction-ordering), here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69403&thanks=69403&ts=1399482444 and here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31116

My understanding is that this is a bug with re-adding fragments during onResume() of an activity.

How can I prevent my Activity from incorrectly ordering my fragments when it is resumed?

My Activity layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: how about adding the fragments in xml in the order you want

Comment: Do you mean to pre-add them into the main layout? Currently my activity does not contain any layout information. I am swapping fragments in-out programmatically and the layouts are described separately in their own layout files. The problem only occurs during orientation change.

Comment: yes use <fragment> tag in the activity to order your fragment

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the following workaround helped:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    bringToFrontIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    bringToFrontIfNeeded();
}

private void bringToFrontIfNeeded() {
    // A fix for a weird google bug
    if (amIOnTop() && (getView() != null)) {
        getView().bringToFront();
    }
}

private void amIOnTop() {
    // depends on you app logic, can be something like
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    return (BACK_STACK_ENTRY_NAME.equals(manager.getBackStackEntryAt(count - 1).getName()));

}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I haven't worked on this for a while now but this is the best solution given.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the fragment in the activity xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I only have one fragment at the start so I don't really want to define 2 static fragments in my Activity layout.

Comment: how are you adding the container , which container are you using ?

Comment: Using the FragmentManager & FragmentTransaction.

Comment: what is your R.id.container ? framelayout ,linear or relative ?

Comment: I'm using LinearLayout.

Comment: This link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31116 shows the root cause. But I don't know how to fix it.